# <%#: %> working locally but causes "Expression expected" on server

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

**This is not a duplicate of the above linked question - I'm fully aware of the difference between the two code blocks, just read the first line of the question!**

(This will only make sense if the "This question may already have an answer here:" is still showing above)

---

I have recently discovered the `<%: %>` inline code block (to automatically `Server.HtmlEncode` the output), as well as the data binding version of `<%#: %>`.

I have a `<asp:Repeater>` which contains several `<%#: %>` blocks which is working locally on my development machine, but causes the following error when published to the server.

> BC30201: Expression expected.

The code works correctly if I convert all instances of `<%#:...%>` to `<%#Server.HtmlEncode(...)%>`

Using `<%: %>` in the code on the server, **does** work.

The application pool in IIS (both my local machine and the server) is setup to use .NET4.0.

Is there anything obvious that could cause the error to happen on the server?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @vcsjones, they have correctly pointed out that I have .Net 4.5 installed on my local machine (which I was positive was not the case).

[This is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) they helpfully provided to see this was case.

Comment: @user2864740, I have just updated my question, because `<%: %>` does work, which would suggest that it *is* running on .NET 4.0, wouldn't it?

Comment: I suspect .NET Framework 4.5 isn't installed. This feature was [introduced in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097391), not 4.0. `<%: %>` has existed since 4.0, but `<%#: %>` was added in 4.5.

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones, but I don't have 4.5 installed either on my local development machine or the server... so why is it working on my local development machine?

Comment: No, @Dalorzo, I'm very much aware of what the difference between `<%= %>` and `<%: %>` is

Comment: you can also visit: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Comment: @freefaller are you sure you don't have 4.5 installed? 4.5 "appears" as .NET 4.0, so you won't see it as a version option in IIS. There is no way this feature is working locally for you without .NET 4.5.

Comment: @vcsjones, I'm looking in `c:\windows\microsoft\framework` (yes, it's a 32bit machine) and v4.0 is the highest installed... same on the server.

Comment: @freefaller .NET 4.5 installs in the v4.0 directory, take a look at [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out exactly which .NET version you have installed. Basically, look at this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`, if the Release value is present, you have 4.5 installed.

Comment: Argh, thank you @vcsjones... you are indeed correct, 4.5 is installed locally. I **really** hope that doesn't have any knock on effect anywhere else, as I am specifically using 4.0 on purpose

Comment: @Dalorzo, I have no idea how the "possible duplicate" has appeared on the question, but it is NOT a duplicate.  If you have the ability, *please remove it*

Comment: @freefaller my apologies it was a missunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because ASP.NET 4.5 was installed locally, and not on the server. The `<%#:` binding syntax was [introduced in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097391). The `<%:` and `<%#` syntaxes existed before 4.5, so that's why they work remotely as well.

The .NET Framework 4.5 is a "drop in" replacement for 4.0, so even if your project specifically targets .NET 4.0, it will still use the 4.5 parser if it's installed, which was happening locally.

Comment: Thanks again @vcsjones. You have to love Microsofts though process on this: "so, we have a separate directory structure for v2, v3 and v3.5, which is useful and safe... but lets not bother with separating v4.0 and v4.5, but just bung it all together instead!"  Genius